# import csv / excel file with special character in kendo grid using jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I'm using import option in kendo grid. Import function works fine. but if I upload file with special character(data) which contains comma(,) cell value gets separated.I don't know whether its a plugin issue.
Please anyone suggest/give me ;solution for my issue

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post your current code so that we can assist you better. Also from a gist of it, it seems your library for parsing excel files is using `,` to split the csv thus putting it in a sperate column

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the CSV from comma delimited to tab delimited.